# A Week after changing nameservers most users are still getting old site

Tags: nameserver, domain-name-system, dns-zone

I changed the nameservers for our client 7 days ago - their domain registrar is `doteasy.com` and I've spoken with them several times over the last few days. I understand that nameservers need to propagate but I don't see why this has taken so long. Doteasy just tells me there is nothing they can do.

When I check the propagation of the nameservers on sites like:

`http://www.intodns.com/`
`https://www.whatsmydns.net/`

I still see the old NS `ns57.1and1.com` and `ns58.1and1.com` and the old A record IP `74.208.118.58`

Our site `uptowngreenville.com` should have the nameservers `ns1144.websitewelcome.com` and `ns1145.websitewelcome.com` and A record IP `192.185.122.201`

We have never had a clients website take longer than 24 hours to be live/fully propagated.

I do notice when I run a check on `http://www.intodns.com/` that the `SOA Primary nameserver: ns58.1and1.com` how can I change this?

Comment: The previous name server record will have had a very long TTL. It's now sat in client's DNS caches with that lifetime. They're not going to make a fresh DNS request until their current (old/incorrect) one dies (TTL expires).

Comment: @i-CONICA I can see if I check propagation on a site like `http://checkdnspropagation.com/` for example, that the TTL for the old nameservers is 86400 - which is only 24 hours. Although I don't know the validity of those "check dns propagation sites".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `websitewelcome.com` effectively delegated the domain to `1and1`:

```
$ dig NS uptowngreenville.com @ns1144.websitewelcome.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
uptowngreenville.com.   86400   IN  NS  ns58.1and1.com.
uptowngreenville.com.   86400   IN  NS  ns57.1and1.com.
```

Also weird, when you trace the resolution, the upstream resolver gives

```
uptowngreenville.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1143.websitewelcome.com.
uptowngreenville.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1144.websitewelcome.com.
```

the former of which is unresponsive. That may be a stale cache, though.

FWIW, your new DNS provider *does* respond with the correct A record

```
$ dig uptowngreenville.com @ns1143.websitewelcome.com
...
uptowngreenville.com.   14400   IN  A   192.185.122.201
```

but as long as it serves wrong NS records, that won't help you I fear.

Comment: why is `websitewelcome.com` (which is hostgator) delegating it to `1and1`? Should I be able to contact them and get it changed?

Comment: Yes, you should most definitely do that. - Perhaps it's their standard practice for domains that are transferred from a different provider.

Comment: thanks - you were exactly right. They found the 1and1 NS at hostgator and removed them. That is their default when adding a new domain to the account.

Comment: everything should be fixed now - except I'm still seeing the old website..

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to wait a final 24h TTL window.